# Windows Desktop 'ghost' rectangles

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I use Windows 7 Ultimate (upgraded from Home Premium) on a 2011 HP desktop PC with 10 GB RAM and Nvidia GeForce GTX550Ti. All related drivers and software updates are installed.

For some time now, after a certain amount of clicking, dragging, moving, renaming, deleting, etc. in Windows Explorer (possibly other software as well), oblong shapes resembling partial rectangles (like wire frames), seemingly random, appear on my Desktop and only disappear after I reboot.

I have been what you might call a 'power user' of Windows and Macs for many years and this phenomenon has me looking for answers.

Update: An attempt to upload a JPG screenshot of the phenomenon I described returned this error message:

Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

This is a text-based description of the lines I described above: ______________________|

I get several shapes like this, of similar length and height (roughly 4"x1").
The more I use the computer the more of these lines appear.
One more note: If I watch a video, these lines appear as part of the video.

Comment: Is there any way that you could post a screenshot? It's difficult to picture this problem.

Comment: Edit your post, and you should see an option to insert picture (near where you can make text Bold or Italic etc)